# Decode Date/Time 62056-21

Tags: parsing, decode

I’m reading data from an electricity meter that’s used IEC 62056-21 protocol.

I have the read command to read the date/time, however I don’t know how to parse it to get the date.
Example Response from meter
“22080670B00021”=
Actual date/time:
2021-10-30 06:08:22

So I can see the hhmmss (220806), but how do I get the date? 30/10/2021 from “70B00021”

Another example:

08000871D00021 =
2021-10-31 08:00:08

Comment: I'm looking at IEC 62056-21 and I don't see anything like your examples. Timestamps are supposed to be in yymmddhhmmss format, not ssmmhh... like you have. That said, the final "21" might be the year (ignoring the century), and the "70" or "71" might be a day counter, where Sept 21 is day 1 (since the standard does talk about seasons and day counters), but it seems a bit unlikely. Are you sure you're getting bytes directly from the meter, without any interpretation/reformatting in between?

Comment: Hi Michael, 100% this is the raw data from the meter. I’ve worked out the date (-40 gives you the date). So today the example is 46191541110021 which should be 2021-11-01 15:19:46. 41-40 = 1st (Which is correct), yesterday it was 71(-40) which is 31st. Still can’t work out how I get 10/21 as the mmyy?